# determining row indices of data.table group members

Tags: r, data.table

The data.table package in R provides the option:

> which: ‘TRUE’ returns the integer row numbers of ‘x’ that ‘i’
>             matches to.

However, I see no way of obtaining, within `j`, the integer row numbers of 'x' within the groups established using `by`.

For example, given...

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6))
```

...I would like to know the indices into DT for each value of y.

The value to me is that I am using a data.table in parallel with Another Data Structure (ADS) to which I intend to perform groupwise computations based on the efficiently computed groupings of the data.table.

For example, assuming ADS is a vector with a value for each row in DT:

```
ADS<-sample(100,nrow(DT))
```

I can, as a workaround, compute the groupwise mean of ADS determined by DT$y the group if I first add a new sequence column to the data.table.

```
DT[,seqNum:=seq_len(nrow(DT))]
DT[,mean(ADS[seqNum]),by=y]
```

Which gives the result I want at the cost of adding a new column.

I realize that in this example I can get the same answer using tapply:

```
tapply(ADS,DT$y,mean)
```

However, I will not then get the performance benefit of data.tables efficient grouping (especially when the 'by' columns are indexed).

Perhaps there is some syntax I am overlooking???

Perhaps this is an easy feature to add to data.table and I should request it (wink, wink)???

Proposed syntax: optionally set '.which' to the group indices, allowing to write:

```
DT[,mean(ADS[.which]),by=y,which=TRUE]
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. Can you give an example of a computation that you want to perform between ADS and DT?

Comment: Blue, I did give a working example... my last line of code is computing the groupwise mean in ADS using indices from DT.   In my _real_ application, the ADS data structure is NOT a vector but a 'GenomicRanges' object, and my DT is meta-data about the ranges.  In any case Josh and Matthew, below, are 'on the case'.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Available since `data.table` 1.8.3 you can use `.I` in the `j` of a `data.table` to get the row indices by groups...

```
DT[ , list( yidx = list(.I) ) , by = y ]
#   y  yidx
#1: 1 1,4,7
#2: 3 2,5,8
#3: 6 3,6,9
```

Answer (score 6):

A keyed data.table will be sorted so that groups are stored in contiguous blocks. In that case, you could use `.N` to extract the group-wise indexing information:

```
DT <- data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6))
setkey(DT, y)

ii <- DT[,.N, by=y]
ii[, start := cumsum(N) - N[1] + 1][,end := cumsum(N)][, N := NULL]
#    y start end
# 1: 1     1   3
# 2: 3     4   6
# 3: 6     7   9
```

(Personally, I'd probably just add an indexing column like your suggested `seqNum`. Seems simpler, I don't think it will affect performance too much unless you are really pushing the limits.)

Comment: +11!  (is that a factorial?)  And, yes, OP (thats me) really wants `.I` (or `.which` when `which = TRUE`).  Is it on the table for implementation?

Comment: @josh-obrien, I don't like adding seqNum since that assumes there is no seqNum column already in use, and it is destructive change to an object I don't want to be modifying.  Thx.

Comment: @malcook Yes it's [FR#1962](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1962&group_id=240&atid=978) "Add `.I` (row numbers of `.SD` in `x`) alongside `.N`, `.SD` and `.BY`". It would be quite handy.